# java.lang.NullPointerException while trying to print matrix values in java static

Tags: java, matrix, static, nullpointerexception, return

Could you please please help me
it's my homework in java, i didn't finish it , i just wanted to see if it's working 
this is the code i'm trying to run, from some reason i get error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and i think it's something with the static

```
public  class  Matrix {
public  static int[][] res ;

public static void main () {
    System.out.println(Square());
}

public Matrix () {
    int[][] res = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
}

public static int getElement (int r, int c) {
    return  res[r][c];
}

public static   int getNumberOfRows () {
    return res.length;
}

public static int getNumberOfColumns () {
    return 1;//return res[0].length;
}

public static int Square() {
    int count;
    int row=getNumberOfRows();
    int col=getNumberOfColumns();
    if (col==row) {
        for(int i=0;i< row ;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j< col ;j++) {
                return 5;

                // if (res[row-i][col-1]!=1) {
                //     return 0;
                // }
                // else {
                // 
                // }
            } 
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you get this error?  Did you initialise all the values you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the constructor and initialise your static field correctly

```
private static final int[][] res = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

// no constructor needed.
```

Comment: `final` is great practice and all but I would rather let someone figure out when to use that later on than have them end up frustrated that their code won't compile when they want to reassign the field.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to initialize `res` in the class constructor, which is not actually `static`. It is only run when you create a new instance of the class. You are also not actually setting the `public static` field in that constructor anyway, since you are declaring the `res` you set in the class constructor as its own local variable that isn't visible outside that method.

To initialize the value of your static fields, you can either set them in their declaration statement:

```
public static int[][] res = {{1, 2, 3},
                             {4, 5, 6}};
```

Or, especially if you want to do extra processing, you can use a `static { }` initializer block:

```
static {
    res = {{1, 2, 3},
           {4, 5, 6}};
}
```